# Login Name and Password are same

Tags: oracle, security, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11gR2 [11.2.0.4] mostly, for package deployment a specific ID's password was needed and at that I put a blind guess with username and as same (password=username),

This was alarming for me, now i want to check same for other users, i have googled but found nothing but to check individual users with their password, Hopefully you got my point?

How can i check this ID's password=username? Any script of code/cursors to check username=password?

Regards,

Comment: One way is that you could follow this link [oracle_get_hash_password](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_retrieve_oracle_passwords.htm) use sysdba to get a text file with create all users sql script, then write a script (programming language, powershell....) to check if exists one user having hash(username) = hash_password in that text file.

Answer (score 0):

The way you should be able to check this is by extrating a list of usernames from the database and try to initiate a session with the databases where you use the extracted username as both the username and the password you try to login with.

You could use a bash loop to do so for example.